# Function call fails when object set to null

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why the Javascript from these [slides](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#13) fail?

```
var ninja = {
  yell: function(n){
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
  }
};
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." );

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = null;

try {
  samurai.yell(4);
} catch(e){
  assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reference is still maintained:

```
var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
```

So that call to `.yell()` is fine, however *this* one isn't:

```
return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

That call's actually referencing `ninja` which is now `null`, and `null.yell()` isn't a function :)

[Here's a modified version that shows the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4He2V/).

Answer (score 4):

The recursive function call uses the ninja reference inside yell(), and when you set that to null it can't call ninja.yell anymore because ninja is null.

Change:

```
return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

To:

```
return n > 0 ? this.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

And it works.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `ninja = null` before calling the function.
Javascript functions capture outer variables by reference, so the `ninja` identifier inside the function refers to the *current* value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

`Samurai.yell` is a "copy" of the function from `ninja`. In that function, it referenced `ninja`, which no longer existed when `Samurai.yell` was *executed*.